# Mysql Copy OR Migrate only one table which contains image

Tags: mysql, copy, migration, blob

I have table named 'tbimage' which contains MEDIUMBLOB type 'image' field.
I tried to export this table to backup and copy to another Mysql server. But when I right-click on table from navigator and click 'Table Data Export Wizard', cannot export it as csv and json both: the former doesn't have blob data, and the latter not working at all.

I searched in many ways, but I don't know how to do. Does anyone knows the solution?

Comment: Export data by `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` query and import data file into existing (already created and empty) table using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Table's DDL must be exported/imported separately (for example, export by `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query and copy DDL into text file for importing).

Comment: which tool are you using ?

Comment: @Shoaeb I'm using mysql workbench.

Comment: mysqldump -u username -p -t  -T/path/to/directory dbname table_name --fields-terminated-by=',' 

you can give this a try..

Comment: @Shoaeb Thanks for you, Shoaeb! I'll try it :)